# Style File to help pdftotext with -layout with text extraction?

Tags: text, translate

I have written a long book in latex memoir.

I now want to feed its content to a machine translator into another language (say, German).  I will use the automated translation for a first pass for a better human translation.

Translators do not understand latex.  There are a couple of methods to go about feeding them.  I could use some online latex parsers, write a quick parser myself, etc.

It occurs to me that I could also ask latex to create a pdf that is better suited to `pdftotext` (poppler).  It should make big spaces between paragraphs, not break paragraphs across pages, etc., probably take out tables and figures, page headings, footings, and sidemargins, footnotes.

(Eventually, I will also need to write a parse-match to integrate the translation back into a latex document that uses the original structure, but just replaces the text.  Thus, I am thinking of adding a number for each paragraph, so that I can take the translation input and output and reconstruct a latex file.)

Has someone written a style file to improve the results of pdf text extraction?  or found a better solution?

Comment: I've used DeepL several times to translate parts of LaTeX documents in source without harm. But for a whole document I would try to convert it to Markdown using, e.g., pandoc. Markdown is often *tolerated* by translators. And after the translation it can be converted to LaTeX again. Alternatively, I would use the translation software for paragraphs instead of a whole document. Usually improving the translation and formatting the text also will be done paragraph by paragraph. Therefore, this seems to me a natural approach. This is, what I usually do.

Comment: I've not tested, but maybe package `stdpage` could help, because it minimizes the formatting a lot. But you would need additional settings like changing the paragraph indent into paragraph skip (AFAIK this is available via options). To minimize page breaks you could use a large page height and add `\clearpage` to every `\chapter`, `\section` etc.